# Batch find command with variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, find

I have a list of string elements.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

CALL SET ListOFElts[0]=First
CALL SET ListOFElts[1]=Second
CALL SET ListOFElts[2]=Third

for /l %%n in (0,1,3) do (

   CALL SET Element=%%ListOFElts[%%n]%%

   whoami /groups /fo list | find "%Element%"
)
```

I want to do attempts of finding each elements with the command `find` but the variable `Element` doesn't seem to be "regognized". When I try this, it outputs nothing for the `Element` variable :

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

CALL SET ListOFElts[0]=First
CALL SET ListOFElts[1]=Second
CALL SET ListOFElts[2]=Third

for /l %%n in (0,1,3) do (

   CALL SET Element=%%ListOFElts[%%n]%%

   whoami /groups /fo list | find ""
)
```

--

I also tried :

```
whoami /groups /fo list | find "%%Element%%"
```

Output of the previous line :

```
whoami /groups /fo list | find "%Element%"
```

--

I then tried (with the use of `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`):

```
whoami /groups /fo list | find "!Element!"
```

Output of the previous line :

```
whoami /groups /fo list | find "!Element!"
```

--

> I want to get this (first loop for instance) :

```
whoami /groups /fo list | find "First"
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpandion.html) for variable `Element`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "ListOfElts[0]=First"
Set "ListOfElts[1]=Second"
Set "ListOfElts[2]=Third"

For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%A In ('Set ListOfElts[ 2^>Nul'
) Do WhoAmI /GROUPS /FO LIST | Find /I "%%~B"

Pause
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what if I have many more "ListOfElts[n]" until like n=100 ? What do I have to change ? I tried to understand the logic of the FOR /F command but I don't get it. Thank you ...

Comment: @MickaëlADRAR, that's fine, apart from setting them, the code remains unchanged.

Comment: Okay thank you ! I'm just curious about the In('Set ListOfElts[ 2^>Nul') code : What does the '2' mean ? I thought I had to adjust that value according to the number of elements.

Comment: In this case `^` is used only as an escape character for the hidden cmd context which runs the content within the parentheses. What is therefore being seen is `2>Nul`, this is a standard error redirection to the `NUL` device, _(effectively preventing the output of error messages)_. The idea is that should the command `Set ListOfElts[` not match any existing variables, an error message, _(`Environment variable ListOfElts[ not defined`)_, would not unnecessarily trigger the `Do` portion.

Answer (score 0):

First, open a command prompt window, run `set /?` and read entire help output for command **SET** on several pages. It explains the usage of [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) on an **IF** and a **FOR** example.

It would be most likely also helpful to read the answers on:
[How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

Your batch file contains `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at top to enable delayed environment variable expansion. But no environment variable is referenced with syntax `!VariableName!` to really make use of delayed environment variable expansion. For that reason `"%Element%"` is modified by Windows command processor already on parsing entire command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)` to just `""` before executing the command **FOR**. The environment variable `Element` is not defined before **FOR** command line is reached and `cmd.exe` parses the entire **FOR** command line with the command block ending with `)` at end of batch file before executing **FOR**.

**CALL** is mainly used to call a subroutine or another batch file from within a batch file. Using **CALL** on a simple command line can be used to get a command line parsed twice by Windows command processor to avoid usage of delayed expansion. On the first three **SET** lines it is absolutely not necessary to use **CALL** as nothing changes on parsing the **SET** command lines a second time.

First solution is without using delayed expansion by using **CALL** to double parse the two command lines in code block.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "ListOFElts[0]=First"
set "ListOFElts[1]=Second"
set "ListOFElts[2]=Third"

for /L %%I in (0,1,2) do (
    call set "Element=%%ListOFElts[%%I]%%"
    call %SystemRoot%\System32\whoami.exe /groups /fo list | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "%%Element%%"
)

endlocal
```

The definition of environment variable `Element` is not necessary in command block as its value is referenced only once. So more compact and therefore faster executed would be:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "ListOFElts[0]=First"
set "ListOFElts[1]=Second"
set "ListOFElts[2]=Third"

for /L %%I in (0,1,2) do call %SystemRoot%\System32\whoami.exe /groups /fo list | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "%%ListOFElts[%%I]%%"

endlocal
```

There is no command block anymore to execute by **FOR** on each loop iteration, just a single command line. But it is nevertheless required to use command **CALL** and use `%%ListOFElts[%%I]%%` as the entire **FOR** command line is parsed already for `%VariableName%` references before executing **FOR** the first time. So `"%ListOFElts[%%I]%"` would be replaced already to `""` before **FOR** is executed at all.

Third solution is with really using delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "ListOFElts[0]=First"
set "ListOFElts[1]=Second"
set "ListOFElts[2]=Third"

for /L %%I in (0,1,2) do (
    set "Element=!ListOFElts[%%I]!"
    %SystemRoot%\System32\whoami.exe /groups /fo list | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "!Element!"
)
```

Fourth solution is compact version with using delayed expansion which is similar to the **FOR** example output by help of command **SET**:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "ListOFElts[0]=First"
set "ListOFElts[1]=Second"
set "ListOFElts[2]=Third"

for /L %%I in (0,1,2) do %SystemRoot%\System32\whoami.exe /groups /fo list | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "!ListOFElts[%%I]!"

endlocal
```

The command **FINDSTR** makes it possible to specify multiple search strings.

```
@%SystemRoot%\System32\whoami.exe /groups /fo list | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /C:"First" /C:"Second" /C:"Third"
```

**FINDSTR** outputs all lines from input stream containing any of the three literally and case-sensitive interpreted strings specified with `/C:"..."`. This single command line in a batch file replaces all four batch files above.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `find /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `whoami /?`

See also answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) for a detailed explanation why on all **SET** command lines `"variable=value"` is used instead of just `variable=value` in the batch files above.

Answer (score 0):

Unless for learning/hidden purposes,
why not simply use

```
for %%A in (First Second Third) Do whoami /groups /fo list | find "%%A"
```

or even

```
whoami /groups /fo list | findstr "First Second Third"
```